# WHERE query in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables. One is called `members` and has a column called `users`. The other is called `sex` and has two columns: `user_s` and `sex`. 
I am trying to create an array comprised of all users from the members table who are
  1) in the sex table and 2) have "men" selected in the sex column.

When I `print_r` this array nothing is displayed even though I can see that there are users who met these criteria. Any thoughts?

```
<?php 
 // test.php
include_once("header.php");
$iaminterestedin = "men"; 
$result = queryMysql("SELECT `user` FROM `members`
                WHERE `user` IN(SELECT `user_s` FROM `sex` WHERE sex='$iaminterestedin')"); 

$combination = array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
{    
$combination = $row['user'];
}
print_r($combination);
?>
```

Comment: What is `queryMysql` did you mean `mysql_query()`?

Comment: queryMysql performs a mysql_query().  It is included as a global function when I include header.php. That part is working fine - I have tested it.

Comment: does it work on the database if you run it like `SELECT user FROM members WHERE user IN (SELECT user_s FROM sex WHERE sex='men')`?

Comment: Inside your `queryMysql(query)` function when you `print(query)` what do you see?  I'm guess the in string substitution that happens inside your function can't see the `$iaminterestedin`, but a better approach would be to use prepared statements and pass in $iaminterestedin as an argument.

Comment: Jason, I think that $iminterestedin will be replaced befonre sending to queryMysql function. The var shouldn't be used unside queryMysql()

Anyway, mysql_* has been deprecated, you should be starting to used mysqli_* soon

Answer (score 1):

You should add values to combination using `$combination[] = $row['user']` or you will always overwrite value on each loop iteration

You also ought to read something about JOIN tables, this will help you a lot with queries like that. For example you will use:

```
SELECT user FROM members INNER JOIN sex ON sex.user_s = members.user
WHERE sex '$iamintererstedin'
```

If you add a foreign key (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) from sex to users this will improve query performance when it gets bigger and time becomes a problem

Comment: This is true but I suspect this the second problem the OP is experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the line

```
$combination = array();
```

With

```
$combination[] = $row['user'];
```

This is the way to *insert* into an array:

Answer (score 0):

I replaced $combination = $row['user'];

with

$combination[] = $row['user'];

That did the trick.